# Using servo library in tinkercad causing weird behaviour

Tags: c++, arduino, servo, tinkercad

I am using analogWrite() in my code. Everything works fine when I am not using the servo library. In other words, everything is fine when I disable this line //servo_9.attach(9); If I enable this line, the PWM will be wrong and weird. Any idea why the Tinkercad simulator is acting weird?

```
#include <Servo.h>
int led =9;
Servo servo_9;

void setup() {
servo_9.attach(9);

Serial.begin(9600);

}


 void loop() {
 for(int n=0;n<255;n++){
     analogWrite(led,n);
     delay(5);
   }
 }
```

This video shows what is happening:
[click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19YUuzkQI02LLSaCAIhSHZMNhsN8AaY6V/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do you really have the servo and the led connected to the same pin?  How do you propose one pin can do both things?

Comment: Never be afraid to check the documentation.  Reading is fundamental.  Check out the second sentence of the second paragraph under "Usage"  https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/servo/

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the servo library clearly states.

> On boards other than the Mega, use of the library disables
> analogWrite() (PWM) functionality on pins 9 and 10, whether or not
> there is a Servo on those pins.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful. I used pin6, the signal looks much better but still different when the serve line is disabled. I also removed the led.

Comment: Different how?  Is this real life or simulation?

Comment: that was the simulation, not the real hardware.

Comment: Then you don’t know what real hardware will do.  Maybe the problem is the simulator.  There was another question there also that you didn’t answer.

Comment: The signal is not exactly the same. It is like there is some noise. If you don't mind trying it yourself: https://www.tinkercad.com/things/6qIZvzIdVKb-lab2-part1/editel?sharecode=YlA0HPqGmjPHIHpfK7eHQ97BbuZkzDT20J-Zb4untO4

Comment: disable the servo and see the difference.

Comment: No, I don’t work with simulators.  You say it’s different but you won’t give me any indication as to what is different about it.  So I can’t help you.

Comment: It’s probably just the crappy simulator.  Try with real hardware and see what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221876/discussion-between-mohamed-ibrahim-and-delta-g).